# Convert System.Drawing.Graphics to html5 canvas methods via Script#

Tags: c#, .net, drawing, system.drawing, script#

Is it possible to convert standart `System.Drawing.Graphics` methods such as `DrawImage`, `DrawPath` and other to html5 canvas methods such as `context.drawImage` and `context.beginPath(); ... context.closePath();` respectively via Script# or other C# to JS converters?

How can I do it automatically without .js file editing after compilation?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve, more precise what's the purpose? can you show some code?

Comment: @lboshuizen, I wanna port my server C# code for image processing to the client side javascript code.

Comment: Seems to be a fine question ... don't know why it was closed. I think I'd agree with the answer below, where you can create an abstraction. I might even suggest perhaps something more specific to your app, rather than a general purpose drawing context abstraction, but that depends on many factors.

Comment: @NikhilK, ok, but there are `CanvasElement`, `CanvasContext2D` with html5 graphicals methods in your greatest library which satisfy my needs. Thank you so much for library!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue.

The way you draw on the canvas is not completely the same as by using System.Drawing.Graphics. A solution is to create an abstraction over System.Drawing.Graphics like this:

```
public interface IDrawingContext{
   void Save();
   void Restore();
   void DrawLine(int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2, string color, int strokeWidth);
   void DrawText(int x, int y, string text, string color);
   object DrawRect(int x, int y, int width, int height, object fill, string strokeColor);
   object DrawPoly(List<Coordinate> points, object fill, string strokeColor, int strokeWidth);
   object DrawCircle(int x, int y, int radius, object fill, string strokeColor);
   object Transform(int translateX, int translateY, int rotate);
   .
   .
   .
   void Clear();
}
```

In the script# creat a class that implements this interface and made the calls native to the canvas using the script# System.Html.Media.Graphics namespace.
In the C# project do the same but use System.Drawing.Graphics

Next thing is refactoring the existing drawing code to use IDrawingContext instead of System.Drawing.Graphics

Comment: Thank you! If you have already written this code, could you publish it on pastebin.com or source code hosting for help to other developers? :)

Comment: I would, but A. it is not written against the canvas directly but to the graphic modules of Dojo. B. I doubt that my client will agree on it :-)

Comment: it is no longer needed. I discovered there are graphics classes such as CanvasElement and CanvasContext in System.Html.Media.Graphics assembly in Script# that allows to perform basic graphics operations.